FX29 Load Cell - Sleep Mode vs Update Mode
Context
I'm using an I2C based Load Cell the FX29.
I have been having troubles where the I2C sensor does not give me any data unless I manually unplug and replug the sensor while the Arduino sample code is running. The sample code is using the library provided by https://github.com/DarkYendor/FX29K_for_Arduino/tree/46d56e6f7a5978f82b81265b9933078b96f386fb
#include "FX29K.h"
#include <Wire.h>

FX29K g_LoadCell(LOAD_CELL_I2C_ADDR, LOAD_CELL_LBF_RANGE, &Wire);

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);

  g_LoadCell.tare(20);
}

static uint8_t TARGET_HZ = 25;
const uint32_t PERIOD_US = static_cast<int>((1e6 / TARGET_HZ));
void loop() {
  static uint32_t last_time = micros();
  if (micros() - last_time >= PERIOD_US) {
    last_time += PERIOD_US; // gives us jitter vs drift
    Serial.println("Load Cell Data: " + String(g_LoadCell.getGrams()));
  }

}

My investigation so far has led to look at the datasheet, where it shows a diagram from the 'General Working Mode'

My guy feeling is that it is stuck in the SLEEP MODE?
The two commands appear to be:

MR : I2C read/write with no bytes read
DF : I2C read with 2 bytes read

As per 
These are the Logic Analyzer traces of when the device is
Not Working

Working

What has been tried

Connected the Load Cell Power to a GPIO Pin to toggle the power to the load cell digitally (no reliable improvement)


We can see how the 'General Working Mode' flowchart shows indication of a command window 6ms/1.5ms.
It is unclear the significance why there are two times mentioned here, and there is no further mention in the datasheet.
However, it does suggest there is a specific timing required on boot of the sensor to ensure a mode of operation. To do so we can control the power to the I2C sensor by powering it through a GPIO pin (VCC to the GPIO) and adding specific time delays to attempt to trigger a correct command mode.
When testing with the following modified setup() method we now get reliable behaviour:
#include "FX29K.h"
#include <Wire.h>

FX29K g_LoadCell(LOAD_CELL_I2C_ADDR, LOAD_CELL_LBF_RANGE, &Wire);

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Control start-up behaviour
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);     // Connect VCC to a GPIO PIN, here Pin 9
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);   // Turn Off the Sensor by setting to Low
  delay(3);               // Arbitrary time to wait for sensor to power off
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);  // Turn on the sensor
  delay(3);               // Wait a setup time between 1.5ms and 6ms, here 3ms
  g_LoadCell.requestMeasurement(); // Trigger first data request
  // 

  g_LoadCell.tare(20);
}


Look at lines 16 and 17 of your code, and then tell me if you think that IF statement would ever result in a measurement being taken.
